# Rename a known file using a list of string from a .txt file

Tags: java, text-files, rename

I'm trying to write a code that lets me rename a specific file (with known name and directory) using a txt file that has inside it a list of names. Specificly, I want to rename an episode using a txt file that has the names of all the episodes in that season.

This is the code I wrote:
Main class:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws IOException {
            String file_name = "C:/Users/home/Desktop/Friends season 2 titles.txt";
            try {
                ReadFile file = new ReadFile (file_name);
                String[] arrLines = file.OpenFile();
                int i;
                /*for ( i=0; i < arrLines.length; i++ ) { // perhaps i'll use this loop later on...
                System.out.println( arrLines ) ;
                }
                */
                RenameFile newFile = new RenameFile ();
                String file2_name = "C:/Users/home/Desktop/friends_s02e01_720p_bluray_sujaidr.mkv";
                newFile.RenameSingleFile(arrLines[0], file2_name);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
    }
}
```

ReadFile class:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile {
    private String path;
    public ReadFile(String filePath){
        path = filePath;
    }
    int readLines() throws IOException {
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String aLine;
        int numOfLines = 0;

        while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null){
            numOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();
        return numOfLines;

    }
    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {


        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData = textReader.readLine();
        }
        textReader.close( );
        return textData;
    }

}
```

RenameFile class:

```
import java.io.File;
public class RenameFile {
    public void RenameSingleFile(String file1_path, String file2_path){
        File oldName = new File (file1_path);
        File newName = new File (file2_path);

        if(oldName.renameTo(newName)) {
             System.out.println("The file has been renamed to: " +newName);
          } else {
             System.out.println("The file could not be renamed.");
          }
    }   
}
```

For some reason, when I run this program I get this message in the console:
"The file could not be renamed.", which means that there's something wrong with my RenameSingleFile method (or with the parameters file1_path and file2_path of that method).

I don't know what is wrong with this piece of code...

Comment: You should output both names along with that error message to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RenameSingleFile` method you should put `file2_name` (the title to be renamed) as your first parameter, and include the directory path and file type when naming:

```
newFile.RenameSingleFile(file2_name, "C:/Users/home/Desktop/" + arrLines[0] + ".mkv")
```

Comment: rookie mistakes (both of them). thanks a lot for your help!